# SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext returns false

Tags: c#, dpi

I have an application that is DPI unaware. I would like to programmatically inform the OS about it.

using this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(int dpiFlag);

[DllImport("SHCore.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS awareness);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();


public enum PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS
{
    Process_DPI_Unaware = 0,
    Process_System_DPI_Aware = 1,
    Process_Per_Monitor_DPI_Aware = 2
}

public enum DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT
{
    DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE = 16,
    DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE = 17,
    DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE = 18,
    DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 = 34
}
```

I have implemented the following method:

```
public static void SetDpiAwareness()
{
    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(6, 3, 0)) // win 8.1 added support for per monitor dpi
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(10, 0, 15063)) // win 10 creators update added support for per monitor v2
        {
            var r = NativeMethods.SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext((int) NativeMethods.DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT.DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE);
        }
        else
        {
            NativeMethods.SetProcessDpiAwareness(NativeMethods.PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS.Process_DPI_Unaware);
        }
    }
}
```

I do a call to `SetDpiAwareness` very early in my application in the first lines after initializing loggers.

However the return value from `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext` is always false and indeed it can be seen from the rendering that the call did not work.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: The DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT enum declaration is just wrong.  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE is -1, DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE is -2, etc.  Throw new Win32Exception when  the return value is *false* to discover this.  How you turned off the version lies is not very obvious btw, beware that the program might not run on an OS older than win10.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/dpi-awareness-context for correct values. Also the docs say "It is recommended that you set the process-default DPI awareness via application manifest, not an API call"